# SearchView retrieving wrong data with List View

Tags: android-studio

When searching for an item, I'm able to retrieve the `Title`, `Artist`, and `Image` for the respective Songs. However, the first 2 items displayed in the `ListView` when clicked on keeps returning the last song in my list instead of the correct song that is being displayed.

E.g, When clicking on "Life is Good" or "Good as hell", the song "First Time" will be displayed instead. However "Perfect", "Lemon", and "Autopilot" are working fine. These are the only codes used to search! `SearchByTitle` and `GetTitle()` are taken from the files where the songs are hardcoded in!

My Activity:

```
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private SongCollection songCollection = new SongCollection();
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    

        stringArrayList.add("Life is Good");
        stringArrayList.add("Good As Hell");
        stringArrayList.add("Perfect");
        stringArrayList.add("Lemon");
        stringArrayList.add("Autopilot");
        stringArrayList.add("First Time");
    
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArrayList);
    
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        adapter.getItem(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String value = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Song selectedSong = songCollection.searchByTitle(value);
                AppUtil.popMessage(view.getContext(), "Streaming song: " + selectedSong.getTitle());
                sendDataToActivity(selectedSong);
            }
        });
 }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

XML to my Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#404040"
    tools:context=".SearchActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#404040">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:divider="@color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you need to create a new list which would contain the search results, you don't have to do the search operation with your original list which is`stringArrayList`

Instead create a new list which is `mylist` in this case, and store the search results and call that list in `onQueryTextChange`

Create this method, I modified the code according to your code

```
private void search(String str) {
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Quote object : stringArrayList) {
            if (object.GetTitle().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())) {
                myList.add(object);
            }
        }
        AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(this, myList);//, swiper
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
    }
```

Now, call this method under search `setOnQueryTextListener`, like this

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    search(newText);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

**OPTIONAL**
And one more modification which you can do is you can check `setOnQueryTextListener` when ever there is some text in it, like this

```
if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    search(s);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

If my answer solves your problem you can give me an up-vote and mark my answer as correct, by clicking on the gray tick button beside the starting of my answer, which will then turn green!

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I'm a beginner at Android Studio, thus could you explain on what ArrayList<Quote> myList = new ArrayList<>(); is, like a new java file or?

Comment: I changed it in my code. Actually I took this code from my project and forget to change that line. You should write `String` there and use it!

Comment: Thats not a new new java file. Its a new arraylist to store the search results.

Comment: I see! I've modified the adapterclass to fit my own application and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: I've got <15 reps, still too little to upvote, I upvoted but it doesn't change the publicly displayed post score :c

Comment: OK I upvoted your question, this may help you to get your reps up! :p